# Alguém conhece uma função no excel ou outro programa para contar a quantidade de números existentes entre um intervalo de números?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Queria encontrar a quantidade de números existentes em um intervalo de números. De modo que eu não precise ficar procurando os números manualmente q se encontram na faixa de valores.

Ex: 0,340-0,345. Tendo como resposta: 6 (0,340 . 0,341 . 0,342 . 0,343 . 0,344 . 0,345).

Comment: Se é para Excel porque você colocou a tag C? A que conjunto de números você se refere? Inteiros? Reais? Se for o conjunto de reais então matematicamente posso adiantar que são infinitos. A representação de números reais em um computador (float ou double) tem uma quantidade finita mas de qualquer maneira é um número imensamente grande.

Answer (score 2):

No Excel, você pode utilizar a função CONT.NÚM para obter o número de entradas em um campo de número que esteja em um intervalo ou uma matriz de números.

Por exemplo, você pode inserir a seguinte fórmula para contar os números no intervalo A1:A20.

```
=CONT.NÚM(A1:A20).
```

Comment: Mas ele não diz intervalo de células mas sim "intervalo de números".

Comment: A função citada não irá contar nada além de números, portanto ele poderá selecionar tudo, que somente contarão os números daquele montante de dados.

Comment: Eu interpreto intervalo no sentido matemático do termo, como o autor da pergunta diz: um intervalo de números, e não os números existentes num intervalo de células. Mas pode ser apenas um problema de português na formulação da pergunta.

Comment: Isso mesmo. Eu queria uma função q conte a quantidade de número dentro de um intervalo de números. Ex: 0,340-0,345. Tendo como resposta: 6 (0,340 . 0,341 . 0,342 . 0,343 . 0,344 . 0,345).